# Split a Pandas DataFrame where one factor column is evenly distributed among the splits

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to split a Pandas DataFrame into multiple separate DataFrames where one of the columns is evenly distributed among the resulting DataFrames. For example, if I wanted the following DataFrame split into 3 distinct DataFrames where each one contains one record of each sector (selected at random).

So a `df` that looks like this:

```
    id   Name     Sector
     1   John        A
     2   Steven      A
     3   Jane        A
     4   Kyle        A
     5   Ashley      B
     6   Ken         B
     7   Tom         B 
     8   Peter       B 
     9   Elaine      C
     10  Tom         C
     11  Adam        C
     12  Simon       C
     13  Stephanie   D
     14  Jan         D
     15  Marsha      D
     16  David       D
     17  Drew        E
     18  Kit         E
     19  Corey       E
     20  James       E
```

Would yield two DataFrames, one of which could look like this, while the other consist of the remaining records.

```
    id   Name     Sector
     1   John        A
     2   Steven      A
     7   Tom         B 
     8   Peter       B 
     10  Tom         C
     11  Adam        C
     13  Stephanie   D
     16  David       D
     19  Corey       E
     20  James       E
```

I know `np.array_split(df, 2)` will get me part way there, but it may not evenly distribute the sectors like I need.

(Edited for clarity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update per comments and updated question:

```
df_1=df.groupby('Sector', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2))
df_2 = df[~df.index.isin(df_1.index)]

print(df_1)
   id       Name Sector
2    3       Jane      A
3    4       Kyle      A
7    8      Peter      B
5    6        Ken      B
11  12      Simon      C
9   10        Tom      C
12  13  Stephanie      D
15  16      David      D
19  20      James      E
17  18        Kit      E

print(df_2)
    id    Name Sector
0    1    John      A
1    2  Steven      A
4    5  Ashley      B
6    7     Tom      B
8    9  Elaine      C
10  11    Adam      C
13  14     Jan      D
14  15  Marsha      D
16  17    Drew      E
18  19   Corey      E
```

---

Here is a "funky" method, using sequential numbering and random sampling:

```
df['grp'] = df.groupby('Sector')['Sector']\
              .transform(lambda x: x.notna().cumsum().sample(frac=1))
dd = dict(tuple(df.groupby('grp')))
```

Output:

```
dd[1]

   id    Name Sector  grp
0   1    John      A    1
4   5     Ken      B    1
6   7  Elaine      C    1

dd[2]

   id  Name Sector  grp
2   3  Jane      A    2
5   6   Tom      B    2
7   8   Tom      C    2

dd[3]

   id    Name Sector  grp
1   2  Steven      A    3
3   4  Ashley      B    3
8   9    Adam      C    3
```

Details:

- Create a sequence of numbers in each sector group starting from 1,
  then randomize than number in the group to create a grouping key,
  grp.
- Use grp to groupby then create a dictionary, with keys for each grp.

Comment: That works well in my example where you only need one record per group in the new DataFrames. Any suggestions if you had a larger starting DataFrame and you wanted multiple records from each group?

Comment: @T.Shiftlet you have to chance the number in the sample function (here's set to 1) ;)

Comment: @Giuseppe, first thing I tried, but if the number of groups you have isn't equal to the number of records from each group, you get the error `ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'` (setting replace to True simply results in a different error).

Comment: @T.Shiftlet can  you add a larger dataset and different N, and show expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way, you can `groupby`by sector and randomly select from each group with a loop using the `sample` function:

```
for x, i in df.groupby('Sector'):
    print(i.sample())
```

If you need multiple random selection use the `sample` function to specify how many items you want. For example:

```
for x, i in df.groupby('Sector'):
    print(i.sample(2))
```

will return 2 random values from each group.